# R dplyr remove "<NA>" column from table

Tags: r, dplyr

Given data

```
d <- data.frame(g = sample(c(1:5,NA),100, replace = T)
                ,o = sample(c("yes","no",NA),100, replace = T))
```

Is there a one step approach to the following:

```
s <- d %>% group_by(g, o) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(o, n, fill=0) 
s %>% select(which(names(s)!="<NA>"))
```

If I do this:

```
s <- d %>% group_by(g, o) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(o, n, fill=0) %>% select(-c("<NA>"))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in -c("<NA>") : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Comment: Look up the `is.na()` function instead of using `"<NA>"`.

Comment: I didnt know it was also the case with `names()`

Comment: You can use back ticks. `s %>% select(-\`<NA>\`)`

Comment: Any rationnelle for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

names(s) gives

```
"g"    "no"   "yes"  "<NA>"
```

As @Psidom says in the comment, the following works. It matters if you use quotes vs back ticks.

```
s <- d %>% group_by(g, o) %>% 
summarise(n = n()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
spread(o, n, fill=0) %>% select(-`<NA>`)
```